# How to get webcam feed from a website user with python?

Tags: javascript, python, opencv

For my project, I need to make a website that would take the webcam feed of its users, process it with python and return some information about it. The python program processes the feed frame-by-frame and I'd prefer to stick with it. However, I only found how to get webcam feed with JavaScript, so if I were to use it, I'd need to pass the frames to my Python script, which would be very slow.

Is there a way to get the webcam feed with Python? And if not, is it possible to pass the frames efficiently between the two programs?

Comment: See https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html.